# Apache Mina : Different handler for each session

Tags: java, nio, mina

In Apache Mina, is it possible to use different handler for each session?

Comment: What do you mean by different handlers? IoAcceptor method setHandler is on per server-socket basis.

Comment: I mean, earlier there was a SocketConnector.connect() method which had option to pass the IoHandler object while connecting. But I don't see this method in new version.